# Neo4j: How to create new node with two new relatioships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to create a new node with two new outgoing edges? I know how to create one, but I can't figure out how to create a second edge out. Of course, I could do it in a separate MATCH statement, but it seems like it would be cleaner to just create both at once:

```
LOAD CSV FROM ... as ROW
MATCH (father: Father), (mother: Mother)
WHERE father.id=ROW.father_id, mother.id=ROW.mother_id
CREATE (child: Child{ ... }) ->[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(father)
// what about the IS_CHILD_OF -> mother?
```

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, you have to be careful with `CREATE` because when you re-run the query, you may end up with duplications, e.g. of `[:IS_CHILD_OF]` edges. 
Also, when you `MERGE` a pattern, it will create the entire pattern if a part of it does not exist, e.g. when the father is not in the store.

For these reasons, better to use an approach like below, in which I also suggest to use a `:Person` label. You may want to add a `gender` property on those nodes.

```
LOAD CSV FROM ... as ROW
MERGE (child:Person{id:ROW.child_id}) 
MERGE (father:Person {id:ROW.father_id})<-[:IS_CHILD_OF]-(child)
MERGE (mother:Person {id:ROW.mother_id})<-[:IS_CHILD_OF]-(child)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
CREATE (mother)<-[:IS_CHILD_OF]-(child: Child{ ... })-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(father)
```